# Dropdown Wordpress authors wrong permalink | query string

Tags: php, wordpress, drop-down-menu, query-string, author

I put together a couple of dropdown searches and I'm having problems with the authors.

This is the website for my archives page: http://goo.gl/p1RLUm

So if I search for an author it sends me to something like this:
mydomain.com/?author=67

When it should be sending me to this:
mydomain.com/author/username
[here's an actual working author page](http://goo.gl/iCN1jy)

I've tried so many things but it always pull the query string as an answer and can never get it to go away.

Any help is appreciated!

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/author/" method="get">
    <?php
    $args = array(
      'show_option_none' => __( 'Select Author' ),
        'name'             => 'author',
        'orderby'          => 'ASC',
        'echo'             => 0,
        'who'              => 'authors',
    );
    ?>
    <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_users( $args ); ?>
    <?php $replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>"; ?>
    <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>
    <?php echo $select; ?>
    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="View" />
    </noscript>
</form>
```

Ok so updated my code to this. Am I on the right track?

```
<?php $users = wp_list_authors($args); ?>

<?php
    $args = array(
    'show_option_none' => __( 'Select Author' ),
    'name'             => 'author',
    'orderby'          => 'ASC',
    'echo'             => FALSE,
    'who'              => 'authors',
  );
?>

<select name="author-dropdown" onchange='return this.form.submit()'>
  <?php foreach($users as $user):?>
    <option name="<?php echo $user->name; ?>">
      <?php echo $user->name; ?>       
     </option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly for you the `wp_dropdown_users( $args )` function does not have an option to set the value of  names. It is the ids and that's it.

What you should do is use `wp_list_authors( $args )` and then do something like this :

```
<?php $users = wp_list_authors($args); ?>


<select name="yourname" onchange='return this.form.submit()'>
  <?php foreach($users as $user):?>
    <?php //just check how to access the $user name url friendly tag ?>
    <option name="<?php echo $user->name; ?>"><?php echo $user->name?></option>
  <?php endforeach;?>
</select>
```

By doing so you don't need your replace/regex thing and have more control over the users output. I'm guessing your JS does the `window.location.href =` redirection job.

Plus, there's an error with your redirection. You should remove the ? character in your url at submit. I guess it is also done in your JS.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm on the right track. Your code should be $users no users correct? The users seem to be showing and pointing to the correct url but now the dropdown is gone [http://goo.gl/p1RLUm]

Comment: You should replace `users` with `$users` and `user` with `$user`.

Comment: @Jupago You are correct, python mistake for the $. As for the select, there's no more `echo $select`. Just add this as normal html.

Comment: @Jupago my code is corrected. I did some mistakes with $user as Jonathan mentionned. Make sure to check if $user->name exist, if not get the name of the author with the ID. You actually want the slug of it.

Comment: No luck yet @AntoineLeBel , but thanks! looking into WP reference tryint to figure out how to check for if user exist. Can't get the dropdown options to show and the list to go away

Comment: @Jupago check the $args, by default it `echo` the list, you do not want that. Set it to false.

Comment: @AntoineLeBel edited my code above, is that what you meant? create an array and echo false? I also cant figure out how to check for the friendly tag, do you mean something like  "if ( username_exists( $username ) )"

Comment: @Jupago You should be fine now, i edited it. `$args` needs to be pass to the function. You can make it :) Don't forget to accept the answer if it is right.

Comment: :) Thank you so much for all the help, I added your edits, the list is gone but the dropdown is empty.. :/ thanks for bearing with me (goo.gl/p1RLUm)

Comment: @Jupago debug, `var_dump($users)` you'll get by!